# Is StoredProcedureQuery meant for calling Oracle functions with?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

Hello I'm using Eclipselink 2.5.1

I'm wondering, is it possible to call Oracle Pl/Sql *functions* using `javax.persistence.StoredProcedureQuery`?

I tried doing so but get the error `PLS-00221: 'function_name' is not a procedure or is undefined`.

If not, what would be the correct way of calling a function if I want to stick to the JPA standard? There is no type `StoredFunctionQuery`. Would I have to do a `select` statement in a query?

Answer (score 1):

JPA StoredProcedureQuery maps on to JDBC CallableStatement. That's all there is to know. If Oracle "functions" are callable using that then any JPA implementation ought to be able to call them using the JPA API.

If a "Oracle function" is a normal SQL function then you can use them in any normal JPQL statement using "FUNCTION(funcName, args)" in JPA 2.1

Comment: I've tried it and it seems that Pl/Sql functions are not callable statements, because a function returns a value, so it has to be used like variable_name := function_name(1234)

Comment: so you use a native query in JPA then (for everything that isn't _standard_ SQL stored procs)

Comment: Billy good hint, but I'm getting error setting up the query like this:
`select FUNCTION('function_name', 'foo', 1234) from dual`

What would be the correct way?

Comment: To clarify, what should I put in the FROM clause, since I don't want to get anything from the DB(except calling the function), but JPQL doesn't allow blank FROM clauses.

Comment: Dual is not an entity so that is invalid JPQL, so only possible as Native. You haven't defined how you would invoke this normally in an SQL environment

Comment: see stackoverflow.com/questions/25686335/blank-from-clause-in-jpql

Comment: See my answer. He refers to JPQL, and I say if it isn't an entity then you use native